# overlapping date range multiple times

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I need to see how many hours of a given date range, overlaps other ranges, like so:

[ ] represent ranges

```
    [<<-07:00->>                            <<-(next day)01:00->>]
[<<-00:00->>    <<-08:00->>] [<<-20:00->><<-23:59->>][<<-00:00->> <<-08:00->>]
```

The top line is a date range provided by the user. In this example, a the answer should be that it overlaps **6 hours**, and the remaining **12 hours** does not overlap.

This is my current code:

```
    // The float that represents the hours overlapping
float overlappingHours = 0.0;

// Calculate overlapping interval
NSDate *overlapFrom = [spanStart laterDate:userRangeStart];
NSDate *overlapTo = [spanStop earlierDate:userRangeStop];

// Calculate new salary
if ([overlapFrom compare:overlapTo] > 0) {
    // Date ranges do not overlap
} else {
    // Date ranges do not overlap
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitHour fromDate:overlapFrom toDate:overlapTo options:0];
    overlappingHours = [dateComponents hour];
}
```

By supplying different combinations for the four dates provided, I get different results. If I for instance omit the dates and only include the hours and so on.

**Problem:**

- I've set the spanStart to 20:00
- I've set the spanStop to 08:00
- I've set the userRangeStart to 07:00
- I've set the userRangeStop to 01:00, (18 hours later than the userStartRange)

The best I've managed to get is one hour away, by testing different combinations. The problem is that if the userRangeStart and userRangeStop stretches across several days, I can't manage to get the overlapping hours for other than the first day. **How can I sort of make this overlapping detection continous?**

I've really stuck on this, thanks a lot for help!
Erik

**Update:**

It may look like this:

```
a---------------------------------------b
           c-----------------d
```

Or this:

```
           a-------------------------b
c--------------------d          e-------------f
```

Or this:

```
                       a----------------------b
c------------------d           e-------f
```

Or anything else really. There are no rules, so I need a function that works no matter setup

Comment: Add `24 * [dateComponents day]`. Also months. (and years).

Comment: @IanMacDonald I don't see exactly where I would do this, could you please elaborate it? Also, where should I omit / include the dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me you are over-thinking this.

NSDates are actually just a number of seconds since a moment in time. (Midnight on 1 January, 2001, in UTC).

You can convert any NSDate to seconds using the method timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate.

When you do that, your dates are floating point numbers, in seconds. You are then free to do any math you want.

Treated that way, 2 date ranges are line segments on a time line. Calculating the overlap between date ranges becomes simple logic and floating point arithmetic.

Your results will be in seconds, so just divide by 3600 to get the overlap in hours.

Say I have a date range from a to b and another date range from c to d.

They're either NSDates or NSTimeInterval values. The two are interchangeable using timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate.

Say range c:d is later than range a:b, and the beginning of c:d overlaps with the end of a:b

Visualized on a timeline, where the left side is older, and the right side is more recent:

```
a                b
         c             d
```

So, if a, b, c, and d are all NSTimeInterval values, the overlap of the dates would be simply `b-c`. That would be the overlap in seconds. `(b-c)/3600` would give you the overlap in hours and fractions of an hour.

No need to use NSCalendar and NSTimeInterval at all.

### EDIT:

I'm thinking of a struct "span" that contains a start date and an end date as NSTimeInterval values (doubles)

There are simple methods to convert dates to time intervals

```
-[NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]
```

and time intervals to dates

```
+[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]

typedef struct 
{
  NSTimeInterval start;
  NSTimeInterval end;
} span;
```

span a, b, c, d;

A method to see if 2 spans overlap:

```
+ (BOOL) span: (span)  spanA
  overlapsSpan: (span)  spanB;
{
  return
    //The spans overlap if spanB's start is inside spanA
    (spanB.start > spanA.start && spanB.start < spanA.en)
  ||
    //or if spanB's END is inside spanA
    (spanB.end > spanA.start && spanB.end < spanA.end)
  ||
    //or if spanA's start is inside spanB
    (spanA.start > spanB.start && spanA.start < spanB.end);
}
```

And a method to calculate the overlap (in seconds)

```
+ (NSTimeInterval) ovelapFromSpan: (span)  spanA
    overlapsSpan: (span)  spanB
{
  BOOL bStartInsideA = 
    spanB.start >= spanA.start && spanB.start <= spanA.end;
  BOOL bEndInsideA = 
    spanB.end >= spanA.start && spanB.end <= spanA.end;

  BOOL aStartInsideB = 
    spanA.start >= spanB.start && spanA.start <= spanB.end;
  BOOL aEndInsideB = 
    spanA.end >= spanB.start && spanA.end <= spanB.end;

  //  ----A----
  //        ----B----
  if (bStartInsideA && !bEndInsideA)
    return spanA.end - spanB.end;

  //        ----A----
  //  ----B----
  else if (bEndInsideA && !bStartInsideA)
    return spanB.end - spanA.start;

  //  ----A----
  //    --B--
  else if (bStartInsideA  && bEndInsideA )
    return spanB.end - spanB.start;

  //    --A--
  //  ----B----
  else if (aStartInsideB  && aEndInsideB )
    return spanA.end - spanA.start;

  else return 0; //No overlap
}
```

You could also make it work if your span structures contained NSDates. You'd just need to change all your references to span starts and ends to be code like `[spanA.start timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]`

### EDIT #2:

There is another set of cases where one or both of the endpoints match. I just changed the logic above to make all the comparisons include equality. I think that takes care of all the cases, but check that for yourself.

Comment: That's a really clever way to do it, my segments, or ranges, however can also look like ^^ (my edit)

But there can be an infinite amount of these ranges, and they can change. So I need some sort of algorithm to "see" how the ranges look like, geometrically

Comment: I still maintain that doing it using floating point numbers (or floating point ranges with a start value and an end value) is cleaner and easier. The way to figure out the logic is to plot the different overlap cases on a timeline and look at the relationship of the start and end times of each range.

Comment: It's a solid method, but I can't figure out how to efficiently keep track of the calculation and get the correct values. I need some way of visualising it in code. See my update, those are just some of the possibilities

Comment: Excellent answer. I added a few extra scenarios to be checked and it works really great! Thanks!

Comment: Whenever you move away from `NSCalendar`, you have to be aware that [not every hour has 3600 seconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second) (note that this will become relevant for real-time use in just a few months), and that in many places, two days a year do not have exactly 24 hours. @Erik

Comment: I see, what do you think @DuncanC about what Josh said?

Comment: @JoshCaswell one of those days is actually today. I couldn't figure out why the timeIntervalSinceDate / 3600 returned 23 hours, but now I see! Can't I just somehow check that and possibly add the remaining hour manually?

Comment: @JoshCaswell, one more thing. The data retrieved from these methods are not stored on the phone, they're calculated whenever needed

Comment: Josh has a point. You can probably safely ignore leap seconds, but switching between daylight savings time and standard time will throw you off, as will leap days.

Comment: @DuncanC Sorry, my first language isn't english, by "daylight savings time", do you mean summer time? My code omits the dates and sets both the span set by the user and by the code to the 1st of january 2001. It will never leave 1st january, my backend code manages that. Can I manually check to prevent the leap days problem?

Comment: Yes, by "daylight savings time" I mean the way the clocks shift 1 hour forward in the summer and back an hour in the autumn. Yes, I suppose you could write code to deal with leap days.

Comment: @DuncanC As my code makes the dates shift back to reference date and break the dates up into individual 24-hours spans, whereas the results is only spans inside 01-01-2001, I won't have to deal with any leap days or similar occurrences?

Comment: You're probably right about ignoring leap seconds; actually, now that I think of it, I vaguely recall `NSDate` saying that it ignores them too.

Comment: @JoshCaswell provided that my code returns all dates to the 1st of January 2001, what measurements do you recommend me to take considering incidents like leap years, etc?